# Valor de uma consulta a um campo numérico retorna não-numérico

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Estou tentando ler um campo numa tabela que é do tipo inteiro. E também é uma chave primária e auto-increment.

O valor retornado é posto num label (já tentei pôr numa input text também).

Para ler a tabela-alvo e pôr o resultado no label, uso uma instrução JQuery. O evento é o click num

```
<input type='file':
```

O código do  click é

```
jQuery("#idFilFoto").click(function (){
var nSigla=jQuery("#idLblSigla").text();
var tabela = "TabPessoas";
var clausulaWhere = " TabPessoasSigla = '"+nSigla+"'";
var jqxhr = $.post("genericaPegaID.php",{tabela:tabela,clausulaWhere:clausulaWhere},      function(resultado) {
jQuery("#idLblID").text(resultado);
});//fim do post
});//fim do click
```

Isto funciona bem.

No label

```
<label id="idLblID"
```

é posto o valor corretamente. Aparece um inteiro sem espaços antes ou depois.

Agora, quero este valor dentro desse label para usa-lo numa outra tabela.

O preenchimento dessa tabela é feita pelo evento click de um botão.

```
jQuery("#idBtnSalvar").click(function (){
var tabela="TabFotos";
var campos="TabFotosCaminhoArquivo,TabFotosFKPessoas";
var matricula = jQuery("#idLblID").text();
var foto = jQuery("#idFilFoto").val();
var posicao = foto.indexOf("fakepath");
foto = foto.substr(posicao+9);
var valores="'"+foto+"',"+matricula;    
alert (tabela+" : "+campos+" : "+valores);
/*
var jqxhr = $.post("genericaInserir.php",{tabela:tabela,campos:campos,valores:valores}, function(resultado) {
alert("success "+resultado);
});//fim do post
*/
});//fim do botao salvar
```

O bloco comentado acima é porque o campo 'valores' força um erro na instrução Insert Into que tenho na página genericaInserir.php. Lá diz que o valor do campo 'matricula' é não-numérico.

Realmente, se se inspecionar o que estava indo para o 'post' (veja o alert antes do bloco comentado) aparece, por exemplo, assim:

'foto.png',[][]6.

Por favor, interprete os dois colchetes como dois símbolos fechados, como dois retângulos.

Deveria ser apenas o algarismo 6, no caso.

Tentei

```
var matricula = parseInt(jQuery("#idLblID").text(),10);
```

mas o resultado é NaN no alert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu estás a recolher o valor do elemento com o identificador `#idLblID` fazendo uso do método **[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** <sup>(Inglês)</sup> que serve o objectivo de recolher uma string com tudo o que é encontrado dentro do elemento alvo.

Na documentação está descrito que existem diferenças na recolha do conteúdo de navegador para navegador, o que pode justificar um pouco porque é que estás a apanhar caracteres além do número esperado:

> The result of the .text() method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements. (Due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines and other white space.)

Que traduzido:

> O resultado do método .text() é uma string contendo o texto combinado de todos os elementos localizados. (Devido a variações nos interpretadores de HTML dos diferentes navegadores, o texto retornado pode variar em novas linhas e outro espaço em branco.)

A diferença depende essencialmente da tua *markup*, mas se estiver nada mais que um número entre as tags do teu elemento, da forma que estás a pegar esse valor também deveria funcionar:

```html
<label id="idLblID">10</label>
```

[**Demonstração no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/3h6gc/)

## Solução

Sem ver a tua *markup* para analisar o que vêm quando recolhes o valor, a minha solução passa por fazer uso da função [**`$.trim()`**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) que serve para limpar o valor recolhido removendo espaços em branco e outros:

> The $.trim() function removes all newlines, spaces (including non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the supplied string.

Que traduzido:

> A função $.trim() remove todas as quebras de linha, espaços (incluindo espaços não separáveis​​) e tabulações do início e do fim da string fornecida.

HTML com tabulações, espaços em branco e o número 10:

```html
<label id="idLblID">     10 &nbsp;    </label>
```

Recolha e verificação do valor:

```js
var numero = $.trim($('#idLblID').text()); // recolhe conteúdo

alert(numero);                             // alerta 10

alert(parseInt(numero) || 0);              // alerta  10
```

[**Demonstração no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/9vWB5/)

Comment: Muito obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente com o método 'trim'.